# Jbpm complete task with params - Map is empty

Tags: java, rest, jbpm

Im trying to user the following code to complete a task in jbpm:

```
private static RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory restSessionFactory = null;
    private static RuntimeEngine engine = null;
    private static KieSession ksession = null;
    private static TaskService task = null; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            restSessionFactory = RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory.newRestBuilder()
                    .addUrl(new URL("http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console"))
                    .addDeploymentId("jbpm:formularios:1.2")
                    .addUserName("admin")
                    .addPassword("admin").buildFactory();
        } catch (InsufficientInfoToBuildException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        engine = restSessionFactory.newRuntimeEngine();
        
        ksession = engine.getKieSession();
        task = engine.getTaskService();

        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("name", "mary");
        map.put("age", "23");
        task.complete(271, "admin", map);
    }
```

Im have only this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-remote-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.Beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

The taks complete without problem but the the parameters are empty;

Then i tried to use the "PostMan" (Chrome plugin) to do the following  POST:

```
localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/249/complete?map_name=mary&map_idade=23
```

and the task complete without problem but with parameters.

If i start a new process:

```
localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/runtime/jbpm:formularios:1.0/process/formularios.isluis/start?map_nome=mary&map_idade=23
```

The process start with the correct parameters.

Im using Jbpm-console 6.1

Am I missing something???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in the client, there's a line missing in https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/6.2.0.Beta3/kie-remote/kie-remote-client/src/main/java/org/kie/services/client/api/command/TaskServiceClientCommandObject.java#L261

It should also do `cmd.setData(values)`.  Fixing on master now.